How I can I calculate a cost per lead/enquire using two different dataframes?
Every quarter I need to calculate the cost per lead/enquire (CPE) from real estate portals. From a complete table that has all the enquiries in the quarter, I need to filter first all enquiries that came from a sub-origin "portals" (specific column), then I need to count the ocurrencies for each portal (including the portals that had 0 enquiries), and then I need to divide each portal´s number of enquiries by the money spent in it to find its CPE (in a new created column).
I have been using Google Colab.
First I used this to filter data from enquiries table and then count portal ocurrencies, turning it into a dataframe:
enquiries_q1_24_portals = enquiries_q1_2024[(enquiries_q1_2024['Sub-origin'] == 'Portal')]
enquiries_q1_24_portals.groupby(['Origin']).size().sort_values(ascending=False)
enquiries_q1_24_portals = pd.DataFrame({'Enquiries': enquiries_q1_24_portals})
enquiries_q1_24_portals = pd.to_numeric(enquiries_q1_24_portals['Enquiries'], errors='coerce')

Then I used loc to separate the two necessary columns from dataframe "portal_costs" which has the spent values:
portal_costs = portal_costs.loc[:, ['Origin', 'CostQ124']]

And then I merged the two dataframes:
cost_per_enquire = pd.merge(enquiries_q1_24_portals, portal_costs, on = "Origin", how = "inner")

It worked well although it is still missing the portals with "0" enquiries:
Final dataframe with enquiries and costs
Then I used this to divide the columns "CostQ124" and "Enquiries":
cost_per_enquire['CPE'] = cost_per_enquire['CostQ124']/cost_per_enquire['Enquiries'] 

My expectation was to see a final table with "Origin", "Enquiries", "CostQ124" and a new column "CPE", but it returned the error below. Could anybody help me, it seems I am almost there but something is still missing...
Of course, if there is a simpler way of doing this I am totally open to it.
Thank you so much!
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/pandas/core/ops/array_ops.py in _na_arithmetic_op(left, right, op, is_cmp)
    170     try:
--> 171         result = func(left, right)
    172     except TypeError:

10 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/pandas/core/computation/expressions.py in evaluate(op, a, b, use_numexpr)
    238             # error: "None" not callable
--> 239             return _evaluate(op, op_str, a, b)  # type: ignore[misc]
    240     return _evaluate_standard(op, op_str, a, b)

/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/pandas/core/computation/expressions.py in _evaluate_numexpr(op, op_str, a, b)
    127     if result is None:
--> 128         result = _evaluate_standard(op, op_str, a, b)
    129 

/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/pandas/core/computation/expressions.py in _evaluate_standard(op, op_str, a, b)
     69         _store_test_result(False)
---> 70     return op(a, b)
     71 

TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'str' and 'int'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-101-2387cc0817ea> in <cell line: 27>()
     25 cost_per_enquire = pd.merge(enquiries_q1_24_portals, portal_costs, on = "Origin", how = "inner")
     26 
---> 27 cost_per_enquire['CPE'] = cost_per_enquire['CostQ124']/cost_per_enquire['Enquiries']
     28 
     29 display (cost_per_enquire)

/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/pandas/core/ops/common.py in new_method(self, other)
     79         other = item_from_zerodim(other)
     80 
---> 81         return method(self, other)
     82 
     83     return new_method

/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/pandas/core/arraylike.py in __truediv__(self, other)
    208     @unpack_zerodim_and_defer("__truediv__")
    209     def __truediv__(self, other):
--> 210         return self._arith_method(other, operator.truediv)
    211 
    212     @unpack_zerodim_and_defer("__rtruediv__")

/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/pandas/core/series.py in _arith_method(self, other, op)
   6110     def _arith_method(self, other, op):
   6111         self, other = ops.align_method_SERIES(self, other)
-> 6112         return base.IndexOpsMixin._arith_method(self, other, op)
   6113 
   6114 

/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/pandas/core/base.py in _arith_method(self, other, op)
   1346 
   1347         with np.errstate(all="ignore"):
-> 1348             result = ops.arithmetic_op(lvalues, rvalues, op)
   1349 
   1350         return self._construct_result(result, name=res_name)

/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/pandas/core/ops/array_ops.py in arithmetic_op(left, right, op)
    230         # error: Argument 1 to "_na_arithmetic_op" has incompatible type
    231         # "Union[ExtensionArray, ndarray[Any, Any]]"; expected "ndarray[Any, Any]"
--> 232         res_values = _na_arithmetic_op(left, right, op)  # type: ignore[arg-type]
    233 
    234     return res_values

/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/pandas/core/ops/array_ops.py in _na_arithmetic_op(left, right, op, is_cmp)
    176             # Don't do this for comparisons, as that will handle complex numbers
    177             #  incorrectly, see GH#32047
--> 178             result = _masked_arith_op(left, right, op)
    179         else:
    180             raise

/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/pandas/core/ops/array_ops.py in _masked_arith_op(x, y, op)
    114         # See GH#5284, GH#5035, GH#19448 for historical reference
    115         if mask.any():
--> 116             result[mask] = op(xrav[mask], yrav[mask])
    117 
    118     else:

TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'str' and 'int'


Your question is missing formatting and a clear [mre]. Please read [ask].

Column 'CostQ124' has str data, not numeric data. Moreover, it uses commas as decimal separators and dots as thousands separators. Python, on the other hand, uses dots as decimal separators on numeric types.
So you need to replace these characters and convert to a numeric type before you can do any calculations.
Given that we have no idea what your original data looks like, starting from the cost_per_enquire dataframe (pictured in the image in your question) you can do:
cost_per_enquire["CostQ124"] = pd.to_numeric(
    cost_per_enquire["CostQ124"].str.replace(".", "").str.replace(",", ".")
)

cost_per_enquire["CPE"] = cost_per_enquire["CostQ124"] / cost_per_enquire["Enquiries"]

               Origin  Enquiries  CostQ124          CPE
0           Idealista        199   4655.59    23.394925
1         Green-Acres         51   2927.00    57.392157
2           Rightmove         42   4497.43   107.081667
3               Kyero         35   1800.00    51.428571
4       James Edition         23   1333.33    57.970870
5     Mer et Demeures         19    540.00    28.421053
6              Zoopla          5    350.72    70.144000
7  Immobilienscout 24          2    787.60   393.800000
8        ListGlobally          1   1134.00  1134.000000


Sorry, something is not right...the original enquiries dataframe has 12 rows, the cost dataframe has 12 rows, but the final one returns only 8 rows...

@RafaelFontes That is completely unrelated to the error you posted. The dataframe in your image already has 8 rows. Again, I have no idea what your data before that looks like, because you haven't shared it in the question. If you have more than one problem, isolate each with a minimal reproducible example, and ask different questions.

Read this in addition to the link shared by mozway in the other comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples
